# Off page scrolling issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

Now this really has me stumped. I'm not going to use a codepen because I simply can't recreate it until I identify the problem. Currently, I'm using Google Chrome. The problem doesn't exist in Modzilla Firefox, Microsoft Edge, Internet Explorer, or Opera.

It's an issue with usually a simple fix. The page scrolls horizontally off the page canvas. I believe it may have something to do with the fact that my laptop I'm viewing the page on has a touchscreen, but most likely not.

I've tried a number of hacks to fix it, including:

1) Tried to put set the `max-width` of the browser to the `innerWidth` with javascript.

2) Tried to add `overflow:hidden` to the CSS of the outer container of my off-canvas menu.

3) I even used the Chrome Dev Tools to delete each element at the time to try and identify the problem. Until EVERY visible element was gone, the problem remained.

4) Set `overflow-x:hidden` on `html` and `body`

5) Also tried to add the following javascript try and to debug:

```
var docWidth = document.documentElement.offsetWidth;

[].forEach.call(
  document.querySelectorAll('*'),
  function(el) {
    if (el.offsetWidth > docWidth) {
      console.log(el);
    }
  }
);
```

6) Tried all of these at the same time.

Therefore, I'm completely stumped.

Here's the link to the site: [The Problem](http://digitaljoe.co)

Comment: I can't reproduce it in Chrome, but in Safari I can make the window scroll widely to the right if I scroll down and to the right as the Leo Burnett quote animates in from the upper right. Something in this animation seems to have a side effect of widening the document. You can even see if you scroll up that the hamburger seems to be missing but is fixed off to the right and invisible against the white background. Adding `body` to the `overflow-x: hidden` rule you already have on `html` seems to prevent this from happening in Safari, but I'm not sure why it's happening.

Comment: As far as the Chrome issue. Here's two screen shots of the screen scrolled left and scrolled right: https://puu.sh/vefvX/591f968ac9.png , https://puu.sh/vefyb/0c1898dfee.png . Unfortunately, I don't have a mac so I can't see the Safari issue. Can you screenshot it?

Comment: @denmch - Tagging you in the comment above.

Comment: Here's a screen shot from Safari showing all elements highlighted, which reveals the hamburger fixed off to the upper right: https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82724/Screenshot%202017-04-08%2022.37.31.png

Comment: What about this?
`html {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}`

Comment: @denmch It was a really good idea, however, this is the result unfortunately ): https://puu.sh/vehqa/21eb18a472.png , https://puu.sh/vehs8/c2d2ab5fcd.png

Comment: @denmch Can you upvote this? We're going to need reinforcements.

Comment: Does anybody have a clue about this?

Comment: I don't think I understand the problem. What I thought you were describing was solved by my last suggestion and I don't quite see what your actual issue is.

Comment: @denmch Notice the spacing between the top left logo and the left side of the page in the screen shots I sent above. The first screenshot is when the page is horizontally scrolled left, the right one is when it's scrolled all the way right.

Comment: The page shouldn't scroll horizontally at all.